# My question was downvoted after it was closed, can I ask the community to delete it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I have this question:

[Bomb attached to accelerating charge, as viewed from a co-moving frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672714/bomb-attached-to-accelerating-charge-as-viewed-from-a-co-moving-frame)

Now it was closed, and then it was downvoted. I do not understand why we are allowing downvotes (or any votes) on closed questions. But that is not the only question here I am trying to ask, rather, if after this I can ask the community to delete this question.

Currently, it has no answers, and is in a net downvote.

I do not understand why it was closed as a duplicate, because I specifically stated I am not asking about gravitational acceleration (free-fall). None of the stated questions answer my specific question.

I asked for re-open, but nothing is happening.

I am sincerely asking for one of the following:

1. please community delete it
2. please re-open, and give people a chance to answer my specific question (which I believe has not been answered)

I am aware that I am able to delete the question, but that would affect my contribution record. I think it would be fair if community would give a chance to re-open or delete it.

By the way, since it was closed, I edited to make it more clear and have a real question at the end.

Comment: Related: *[Any point to downvoting already closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113955/)* and *[Why allow closed questions to be voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83798/)*.

Comment: "I am aware that I am able to delete the question, but that would affect my contribution record" $-$ the same would be true if the question was deleted by others. Why do you think this is not the case?

Answer (score 15):

1. The question failed the [reopen review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/361144) with no vote to reopen. From the timing it is evident that least two of the three reviewers saw your edited version and did not think it merits reopening. Note that the lack of an explicit question was not the reason for closure as a duplicate, and your edit did nothing to address my point that it is unclear how this question is substantially different from the similar paradoxes in the linked duplicates.
2. Since the question does not have any answers, you should be able to delete the question yourself. None of the [criteria that block self-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/263383) of questions seem to be fulfilled.

   In general, we do not delete closed questions unless there is a specific reason (e.g. rude or spammy content) - being off-topic alone does not merit deletion, and would prevent reopening altogether. Note also that deleting a question counts against you in the eyes of several automated quality measures like the [positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/263383) *in addition* to it being closed, i.e. a closed and deleted question is twice as bad as merely a closed question with respect to these measures. This is true *regardless* of whether the question was self-deleted or deleted by any other process.